# Mysql Sleeping connections keeping rows locked

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an application developed in C# which uses MySql as Database. sometimes, when inserting or updating records application faces locked timeout expired error.

I noticed that there were some sleep commands (show full processlist;) which were locking some rows.

Why sleeping commands are locking the rows???

On my server, sleeping commands got killed after 8 hours as shown in

```
show variables like 'wait_timeout';
```

and

```
show variables like 'interactive_timeout';
```

**Is it OK to set this timeout for 30 seconds by following queries?**

```
SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=30;
SET @@GLOBAL.interactive_timeout=30;

SET session wait_timeout=30;
SET session interactive_timeout=30;
```

Comment: Sleeping connections do not *cause* this.  Incorrect code that leaves transactions running without a commit or a rollback cause this.  Find and fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Mysql connection gets terminated (because of network issues) before commit or rollback. And this is causing locks. is there a solution for this???

Comment: We don't see any c# here. The MySql provider for .net has a known bug related to command/connection. Without this info, not possible to say anything. The bug reference https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89159.

Comment: One option is you are not disposing connection objects properly. Connections should be created as part of a `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a tradeoff. On one hand you have performance savings from pooling connection for longer time. On the other hand, you may get into situation where a power outage (or a bug) can cause a connection that holds locks to be abandoned by the client. As a result, from MySQL perspective, you have a valid connection that happens to hold locks and it will only close it after 8 hours of inactivity (default `wait_timeout` period). Similar question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/324312/18720